# cannot save UserDefault array in certain iPhone simulators (swift 3)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm saving an array using `UserDefault` and for the most part it's working incredibly great. However in some simulators such as iPhone 7, iPhone 5 (iOS 9.3), and iPhone 6 (iOS 9.3) the simulator crashes in the line where I try loading one of my arrays from UserDefaults.

```
@IBAction func AddGraphComponent(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var weighText:UITextField!
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter new Weight!", message: "Please enter your Weight, followed by the date in which your weight was recorded", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addTextField { (weighText) in
        weighText.placeholder = "Weight"
        weighText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    }
    alert.addTextField { (dateText) in
        dateText.placeholder = "Date (MM/YY)"
    }
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (_) in
        let field = alert.textFields![0] as? UITextField
        let weigh = alert.textFields![1] as? UITextField
        if (field?.text)! == "" || (weigh?.text)! == "" {
            let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Please fill in BOTH fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else {
            print((field?.text)!,(weigh?.text)!)
            let dataInt:Int = Int((field?.text!)!)!
            self.chartData.append(dataInt)
            self.chartLegend.append((weigh?.text)!)

            var weighting = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartData") as! [Int]
            var dating = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartLegend") as! [String]// this is where the error is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

            weighting.append((dataInt))
            dating.append((weigh?.text)!)


            self.kUserDefault.set(weighting, forKey: "chartData")
            self.kUserDefault.set(dating, forKey: "chartLegend")
            self.kUserDefault.synchronize()

            self.lineChart.reloadData()

            print("\((dating))")
            print("\((weighting))")
        }
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(confirmAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

at the line where I write `var dating = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartLegend") as! [String]` my code crashes on said device simulators. I wonder as to why this is. Is there an error in my code, or is this a bug?
I'm using swift 3 on Xcode 8.0

Comment: FYI - the issue you are seeing here is one prime example of why you must always delete your app from any devices/simulators you have been developing with, then do a clean build and fresh install, followed by thorough testing of your entire app before sending your app to Apple. It's not uncommon for things to work on development devices over time but crash when freshly installed.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for advising me that! I will definitely keep what you said in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening most likely because UserDefaults doesn't find anything named 'chartData' or 'chartLegend' and then reading it as nil. What you want to do is use a if let to safely check if there is a value you can receive.

Take a look here:

```
if let weighting = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartData") as? [Int] {
    //Do your stuff
    weighting.append((dataInt))
    self.kUserDefault.set(weighting, forKey: "chartData")
    print("\((weighting))")
}
if let dating = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartLegend") as? [String] {
    //do your stuff here
    dating.append((weigh?.text)!)
    self.kUserDefault.set(dating, forKey: "chartLegend")
     print("\((dating))")
}
self.kUserDefault.synchronize()
```

As rmaddy commented, it is important that you do a clean install on simulator and real device before testing modified code, especially when you are dealing with read/write from storage.

Edit:

Another approach is to use the guard statements.

```
guard let dating = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartLegend") as? [String] 
else{ 
//dating is nil
}
```

Comment: Thank You! this was very helpful :) is there any way to check the otherwise (if it is indeed a nil)? I've tried just flat out using an `else{` method but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: what is the benefits of using `guard let` approach rather than the simple `if let` method?

Comment: They both unwraps optionals and are mostly the same thing I guess. I often use "if let"

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving the array before you set it, which means there's a good chance it's `nil`, and you are force casting it with `as!`, which is something else you should avoid because in situations like this, it crashes.

I suggest you do `var dating = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartLegend") as? [String] ?? [String]()` instead to prevent the crash, and to get more familiar with optionals in general.

My rule is to NEVER use `!` to unwrap an optional outside of `IBOutlets`. I use `if`, `guard` and `??` instead.